# Intercept POST request sent by jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to implement some validation for the jqGrid. What I want to achieve is as follows. When the user presses complete, I want to validate that the number of the rows in the grid is a particular number, let's say 10. But I want to do this without the request going to the backend. If such validation is not successful, I want to show the user an error message.

I've tried catching different types of events such as beforeSubmit, but none of them were successful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What you mean with "user processes complete" - complete what? Is this a custom button or a button related to jqGrid actions like save, cancel and etc.